# Typescript - base class inheritance

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm trying to understand this legacy code. I understand what is interface, class, but I don't understand why to return `new (this.constructor as any)(this)` from `clone` function? Do you have any ideas?

```
interface IClonable<T> {
  clone(): T
}

export interface IBaseComponent<T> extends IClonable<T> { }

export interface IBaseComponentParams { }

export class BaseComponent<T> implements IBaseComponent<T> {
  constructor(_: IBaseComponentParams) { }

  clone(): T {
    return new (this.constructor as any)(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: It's strange indeed - almost as if it is calling some implicit copy constructor.

Comment: I guess this allows to implement copy constructor in derived class, then use clone method to create clone/copy